# Image recognition

Tags: image-recognition, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I need software using artificial intelligence (neural network) to learn from a few photographs and then recognize if other photographs have similar colors. Is there something I can use out of the box or should I rather write something myself using available open source libraries?

Comment: It will be very hard to train a neural net with only a few photographs.  You will need a larger data set if you want to use a neural net to accomplish your goal.

Comment: Your question is very broad. Why use a neural net? What is your cost function? What do you want to optimize? Define "similar colors"? Why not do it straight off the bat? Do you want supervised learning or just clustering of photos? If so, spectral methods would fit.

Comment: If it's just about colors, it might be much simpler than a neuronal network. [PCG.SE](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing) has image processing questions, e.g. [sort the pixels](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/62686/sort-the-pixels). Neuronal networks can do much more awesome stuff. Just [Google for 'Google Dreams'](https://www.google.de/search?q=google+dreams)

Comment: Or [Sort all pixels by number of occurrences](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47776/sort-all-the-pixels-of-an-image-by-the-number-of-occurrences)

Comment: Also: does it need to be standalone software, or a programming library? What is your input and output going to be? What OS? What price? Please [edit] your text and answer all questions.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of any software that use neural nets, however if you can code with Python or C++ I suggest openCV. Great tool for working with pictures.
I would say openCV is almost ready-to-use, a few line of codes will likely solve your problem. Just google openCV

Otherwise you can always try building something using scikit-learn.

Keep in mind that a few pictures might not be enough to train a classifier.

EDIT: Weka machine learning benchmark is a software that has a GUI and can be used to perform machine learning.
http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/